# bind list of selected value in DropdownButton

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I've a dropdown button inside a listview builder. User will upload multiple files and will select their different types using dropdown button. Listview length will be according to the number of selected files.

```
List<String> _selectedItem = [];
DropdownButton(
  hint: Text('Select type'),
  isExpanded: true,
  underline: Container(),
  value: _selectedItem[index].isNotEmpty ? _selectedItem[index] : null,
  items: _itemList.map((e) {
    return DropdownMenuItem(
      child: Text(e.description!),
      value: e.code,
    );
  }).toList(),
  onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedItem[index] = value.toString();
    });
  })
```

But while I'm using list to get the selected value, it'll throws error `Error :  RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0`.

ListView builder:

```
ListView.separated(
  itemCount: fileList.length == 0 ? 1 : fileList.length,
  separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
   return SizedBox(height: 8.h);
  },
  shrinkWrap: true,
  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
// Other code
```

Here, fileList is number of selected files. Initially it'll be 0 that's why I'm setting it 1 so that user can see the Select File UI. Later the listview will generated according to number of selected files. For example, user selects 2 files. Then there'll be 2 card and each card will contain **File type dropdown, file name and comment**.

How could I store the selected value into list and bind and display it into DropdownButton? Need help to get out from this issue...

Comment: Is there a reason `_selectedItem` is a `List`? Should it not just be a single value?

Comment: Yes. The dropdown button in inside listview. so I've to store its selected value inside list not in a single value.

Comment: Please provide a complete list view builder code

Comment: Shahzaib, I've updated my post. Please have a look and help me to get out of this issue if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line the length is 0 but you assigned it as 1. so there is no value at index 0..

```
itemCount: fileList.length == 0 ? 1 : fileList.length,
```

change it to

```
itemCount: fileList.length,
```

Comment: Then how could I show the UI to user for the first time? I've to set it 1 to display the UI to user for the first time. First time it'll 1 and later the listview will generate according to the length users selected file

Comment: `fileList.length > 0? Listview.separated: Container()`//show some other contenr

Comment: The whole content(dropdown, select file and comment) is in a card. That's why I've to use that condition.

Comment: But in list if there is no data and you access the first element it will throw an error

Comment: Ok, Kaushik. Thanks. I think I've to change the present UI.

Comment: Yeah also it's a good practice to show some ui if the list is empty saying there is no data and render the list only if it has data

Comment: Kaushik, It doesn't work if there's value into fileList.length. Show the same error for ``_selectedItem[index]``

Comment: What's_selectedItem?

Comment: List<String> selectedItemValue = []; To keep dropdown value into list. Cause according to list length there will be dropdown into listview. Say, list length is 2. Then there'll be 2 card and each of them contains a File type Dropdown, File name and Comment.

Comment: Please see the Dropdown part into my post. I've to store and show the list dropdown value.

Comment: _selectedItem is a list with no elements. If you try accessing any element by its index it would throw an error

Comment: Solved the issue. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

it's because `_selectedItem[index]` doesn't yet exists when you first call it.  _selectedItem is instantiated as an empty list (length of 0). so you can't assign something to index 3 (for example).

if you just want to have a list with the selected items you'll have to do a check for that:

```dart
if(_selectedItem.contains(value.toString()) return;
setState(() => _selectedItem.add(value.toString());
```

or if you want your dropdowns to be a toggle instead:

```dart
_selectedItem.contains(value) 
   ? _selectedItem.remove(value)
   : _selectedItem.add(value)
```